# Problems with Querying data from Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am struggling to `Query` data from `Database`.
My code is working in a way, but I have to turn the screen off and on my mobile to get the data to show in my `ListView`.The `TextView` `tvuserstorage`is the value I want to use to filter my `Database` after. I have another `Activity` where I don't `Query`, and that is working just fine from the same `Database`.

Hope someone would see what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_tool_list);

    databaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("").getReference("Ansatte");
    databaseTools = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("").getReference("Verktøy");

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    userID = user.getUid();

    tvuserstorage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_userstorage);
    svusertoollist = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.sv_usertoollist);
    lvusertoollist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_usertoollist);

    usertoollist = new ArrayList<>();
    databaseUsers.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Users userprofile = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);

            if (userprofile != null) {
                String user = userprofile.getUserStorage();
                tvuserstorage.setText(user);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Query userlist = databaseTools.orderByChild("toolOwnerStorage").equalTo(tvuserstorage.getText().toString());

    userlist.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            usertoollist.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){
                Tools tools = snapshot1.getValue(Tools.class);

                usertoollist.add(tools);
            }

            ToolList adapter = new ToolList(UserToolListActivity.this, usertoollist);
            lvusertoollist.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { }
    });
}
```

Here is my log for `userID` right before I use it:

```
I/TAG: xOPruRmASVcwlkEwr8Xr2mlCygw2
```

Here is my Firebase Structure:

```
"Ansatte" : {
  "xOPruRmASVcwlkEwr8Xr2mlCygw2" : {
   "hasUserStorage" : "Ja",
   "userAdmin" : "Nei",
   "userDivision" : "Elektro",
   "userEmail" : "booby@bob.com",
   "userName" : "Bobby",
   "userStorage" : "220"
 },
 "Ak2hetTTcRMLlapYHDZnTqUM1Ch2" : {
   "hasUserStorage" : "Nei",
   "userAdmin" : "Nei",
   "userDivision" : "Blikk",
   "userEmail" : "teddy@ted.com",
   "userName" : "Teddy",
   "userStorage" : ""
```

```
"Verktøy" : {
  "3" : {
    "toolGroup" : "",
    "toolName" : "Wrench",
    "toolOwner" : "",
    "toolOwnerStorage" : "220",
    "toolQRid" : "3",
    "toolStatus" : "",
    "toolType" : "",
    "toolrenteddate" : ""
  },
  "1" : {
    "toolGroup" : "",
    "toolName" : "Pliers",
    "toolOwner" : "",
    "toolOwnerStorage" : "225",
    "toolQRid" : "1",
    "toolStatus" : "",
    "toolType" : "",
    "toolrenteddate" : ""
```

So here is what I want to happen:
When the user `"xOPruRmASVcwlkEwr8Xr2mlCygw2"` is logged in I want to display only if the data from `Verktøy` and `child("toolOwnerStorage)` is equal to `Ansatte` and `child("userStorage)`. And in a way it works with the code I posted, but I have to turn my screen on and off to get it to show. But if I take away the `Query` it shows everything without any problems.

Comment: Please don't pass an empty string here: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("")`. I'm surprised that even executes, but if it does: if you don't need to specify a database URL there, simply don't pass any value: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()`

Comment: Hi Frank, I am not passing an empty string, I have just deleted it for this post.

Comment: OK   --- Can you show what data exists in your database under `databaseUsers.child(userID)` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). --- Can you log and show the value of `userID` right before you use it to access the database? --- If you put a breakpoint on the first line inside `onDataChange` and run in a debugger, does it reach that line?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond with @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen , I have added more information. Hope you could figure this out for me.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the first line inside `onDataChange` for the query and run in a debugger, does it reach that line?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, yes it does.

Comment: OK, that's good to know.  --- Then if you step through that method line by line, and check all values on each line, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I've checked the lines in my `OnDataChange` for the `databaseUsers.childe(userID).add...` And that is returning the right value. So that function is ok. But the `Query` under `OnStart`, i think maybe the problem is there?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I've logged the value from this line: `Query userlist = databaseTools.orderByChild("toolOwnerStorage").equalTo(tvuserstorage.getText().toString());` and that is returning two values. These: `D/TAG:      ` and `D/TAG:H300`. So when I turn of the screen and on again I am getting  `D/TAG:H300` , but when I go back on the application and back again I am getting `D/TAG:     `

Answer (score 1):

I figure this out, hope this is a good solution.
I put the `Query` inside off the `addListener`. And now it works.

```
databaseUsers.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            Users userprofile = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);

            if (userprofile != null) {

                String user = userprofile.getUserStorage();

                tvuserstorage1.setText(user);

                Query userlist = databaseTools.orderByChild("toolOwnerStorage").equalTo(user);

                userlist.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        toolListData.clear();
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()){

                            Tools data = snapshot1.getValue(Tools.class);
                            toolListData.add(data);

                        }


                        sharedToolsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { }
                });


                //Log.d("TAG", user);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }

    });



}
```